# Command line arguments to yarn start

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a react app with `"start": "react-scripts start"` in package.json. I run it using yarn start. However, I want to pass an argument from command line eg `yarn start -- test=hello` and access it it in `index.js`.

I tried to access it using process.argvs but it is not there. How should I pass command line arguments to `yarn start` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that react-scripts take command line arguments.

If you want to pass arguments to node you will have to eject cra, then you will be able to pass arguments to node.